# The general form of a reflection operator

Tags: proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove that every reflection on a finite-dimensional product space has the form $T(v) = v - 2 \langle v, u \rangle u$ for a unit vector $u$. The definition of a reflection I have to work with is: self-adjoint ($\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, Tw \rangle$ for all $v,w$), $T^2 = I$, and $\dim \text{ker}(T + I) = 1$.

I'm not completely sure on how to start. I considered that I could try to prove that $V = \text{Img}(T) \oplus \text{Ker}(T)$, so $v = x + y$ for $x \in \text{Im}(T)$ and $y \in \text{Ker}(T)$. After applying $T$, I get $T(y) = 0$ and $T(x) = T(T(x')$ for an $x' \in V$. As $T^2 = I$, $T(v) = x'$. I'm not sure if there's a way to write this in the above form or if I'm completely off-track.

Comment: First, identify your $u$: it should just be a unit vector in $\operatorname{ker}(T + I)$ (the fact that it has dimension $1$ is suggestive, and you can confirm that $u$ would have to be in this subspace by finding showing $(T + I)(u) = 0$ for the given form of $T$). Then, for a reflection $T$ according to your definition, with unit vector $u \in \operatorname{ker}(T + I)$, I would show that $S(v) = T(v) + 2\langle v, u \rangle u$ is self-adjoint, with all of its eigenvalues $1$. This is sufficient to show $S = I$, and the result follows.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for the very helpful response. I think I'm still somewhat confused, but have made more progress. As $\text{ker}(T + I)$ is $1$-dimensional, I can pick any non-zero element of $\text{ker}(T + I)$ and scale it down to unit length. It seems that this $u$ is not unique and depends on the choice of basis vectors. I tried to then show that the function $S$ you defined is self-adjoint by showing $\langle Sv, w \rangle = \langle v, Sw \rangle$, but after expanding both sides, I wasn't able to reconcile inner products containing $v$ on one side and $w$ on the other.

Comment: You could just consider $Rv = \langle v, u \rangle u$, as $S = I + 2R$, and $I$ is self-adjoint. Then$$\langle Rv, w \rangle = \langle \langle v, u \rangle u, w \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle\langle v, u \rangle$$whereas$$\langle v, Rw\rangle = \langle v, \langle w, u \rangle u \rangle = \overline{\langle w, u \rangle}\langle v, u \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle\langle v, u \rangle.$$